# Can we have upvote/downvote notifications on meta posts back?

Tags: feature-request, voting, meta, top-bar

Reputation on MSO is copied from SO, so votes on posts don't affect it. I'm guessing that as a side-effect there are no top-bar notifications when someone votes on my post. Although meta-voting is different, it doesn't mean that it's completely meaningless.

I think it would be useful to know that community either agrees or disagrees with my post. So, **can we have a way of notifying the user about upvotes/downvotes on their post on MSO?**

We still get notifications about meta badges - which seem really less important than the direct information about feedback on one's posts.

Comment: Yes, because the thing missing from Meta is excessive butt-hurt about downvoted posts.

Comment: On Big Meta: [Make voting activity on your posts available on site metas (what you would get from rep if metas had rep)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/167648/185667)

Comment: @CodyGray "butt-hurt" is a reaction of some narrow group of people to this information. Doesn't mean that this information won't be useful for others :)

Comment: Meh. I sort of like to know my post scores on Meta, but given the lack of notifications, I realized that I don't really care all that much (even though the occasional "You earned a 'Nice/Good Answer/Question' badge" is nice).

Comment: @CodyGray I find "butt-hurt" to be an unhelpful term. It's a way of dismissing a person because they're upset, and dismissing someone because they're upset doesn't help solve the problem. Maybe they shouldn't be upset, but sometimes it's a learning process to get used to negative feedback. And sometimes being upset has more to do with poor presentation of negative feedback than it does with the feedback itself.

Comment: Oh boy, butt-hurt over the term butt-hurt. Should've seen that one coming, I suppose. It is a way of dismissing *concern over an issue* because of an unconstructive and overly emotional presentation. If you haven't seen that on Meta regarding downvotes...welcome and thanks for stopping by!

Comment: @CodyGray Seems you have a strange butt-hurt fixation ;P jpmc26 (and some other people) simply disagrees with you - doesn't seem from his comment that his butt hurts, looks pretty calm.

Comment: @CodyGray Comes from personal experience, really. Someone recently said something very unkind and treated me poorly. (Not on StackOverflow.) I didn't really respond exactly the right way, but when they said I was "butt-hurt," it just made me feel worse. Truth is, that just made me want to argue with the person even more. Using it can never help, and it can hurt. So why use it? The only reason you would use it is because it makes *you* feel justified about being unkind.

Comment: @CodyGray So no, not butt-hurt. Just hurt because someone decided I wasn't worth caring about how their words make me feel. That somehow, something is wrong with *me* because their words hurt me.