# Why don't I get notified of an upvote or downvote on Meta?

Tags: support, voting, meta, notifications

Why don't I get notified of an upvote or downvote on my posts on Meta, like what happens on the main site?

Comment: Feature request to fix this on MSE: [Make voting activity on your posts available on site metas](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/167648)

Comment: Because there would be too much whining. There already is more than enough. Please don't make it worse.

Comment: see also [Can we have upvote/downvote notifications on meta posts back?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258179/can-we-have-upvote-downvote-notifications-on-meta-posts-back)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You get notifications when your *reputation* changes, not when somebody votes on your post. You might think this doesn't make a difference, but e.g. after reaching the [daily maximum of 200 points](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/268901/4751173), you won't get notifications for upvotes anymore.

Because up- and downvotes on Meta don't change your reputation, you don't get a notification.

Comment: thank you @Glorfindel, this maybe answer my question :)